# Python Tinter dropdown menu command with click event

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I have a TKinter dropdown menu created with this code:

```
#menu
menu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu = menu)
subMenu = Menu(menu)

menu.add_cascade(label = "Kies een ander station", menu = subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label = "Amersfoort", command = print('test'))
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label = "Amsterdam Centraal", command = print('test2'))
subMenu.add_separator()
#etc..
```

When I compile and run, the code in the `command` attribute of each `subMenu.add_command()` function is being executed right away. I want to achieve this when I click on a menu item. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in lambdas. This will make the expressions into callables which will patiently wait for the event to occur before executing.

```
subMenu.add_command(label = "Amersfoort", command = lambda: print('test'))
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label = "Amsterdam Centraal", command = lambda: print('test2'))
```